# Connection Qt with cooca

Tags: macos, cocoa, qt

I am work on Qt. I want to create a connection cocoa with qt in qt project. In this connection how to import coca framework i.e ImageIo framework. which exist in this path /system/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ImageIo.framework.

If I am apply this stament #import  ,this statement through error ImagIo/Imageo.h : No such file or directory.

In this framework I am access to CGImageDestnationCreateWithUrl function.

Answer (score 5):

To include an OSX framework, just add it to your .pro file. For example, to include the Core Foundation libraries you'd add: -

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/
LIBS += -framework CoreFoundation
```

Therefore, for the ImageIO framework it would be:-

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F /system/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ImageIo.framework
LIBS += -framework ImageIO
```

It may be that you only need to add the path up to ApplicationServices.framework, if that includes ImageIO, but if not, add the full path.

Comment: Hi,  After adding the framework, CGImageDestnationCreateWithUrl function is not access ,this function is lies CGImageDestinatin.h class ,this class is subclass of ImageIo.h class.                     how to access CGImageDestnationCreateWithUrl this function in .mm class.

Comment: Hi, My main concern is ,How to use  CGImageDestnationCreateWithUrl()  cooca function in Qt project in .mm class.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding your question. Are you trying to use Qt within an XCode Cocoa project, or trying to use the Core Foundation function CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL within a Qt project? If it's a Qt project, there should not be a .mm file.

Comment: Hi, I am manually adding .mm class. In this class I am access to coca class like  CIMageRef,NSURL class etc. but why i am not access the   CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL() function this function exist in GImageDestinatin.h class. this class path is /system/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ImageIo.framework/Headers/GImageDestinatin.h